# pytest doesn't find the test

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I try to make a simple test with assert statement like this

```
def sqr(x):
    return x**2 + 1 

def test_sqr():
    assert kvadrat(2) == 4

! pytest
```

and it returns

[image]

If anyone has any ideas what might be wrong.

Comment: Do you run this in an IPython notebook?

Comment: Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2):

For `pytest` to find the tests these have to be in a **file** in the current directory or a sub-directory and the filename has to begin with `test` (although that's probably customizable).

So if you use (inside a Jupyter notebook):

```
%%file test_sth.py
def sqr(x):
    return x**2 + 1 

def test_sqr():
    assert kvadrat(2) == 4
```

That creates a file named `test_sth.py` with the given contents.

Then run `! pytest` and it should work (well, fail):

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: D:\JupyterNotebooks, inifile:
plugins: hypothesis-3.38.5
collected 1 item

test_sth.py F                                                            [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_sqr ___________________________________

    def test_sqr():
>       assert kvadrat(2) == 4
E       NameError: name 'kvadrat' is not defined

test_sth.py:5: NameError
========================== 1 failed in 0.12 seconds ===========================
```